# Cannot run program.The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: pycharm

After updating my Windows laptop, I tried running my PyCharm programs. However I pressed run and got this error

> "Error:Cannot run program "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyCharm\Scripts\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified". I went into edit configurations and saw this "[invalid] Project Default (Python 3.9 (PyCharm)) C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyCharm\Scripts\python.exe".

Answer (score 1):

Update the interpreter in `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter`, see help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter